# Artifactory expiration of pypi artifacts

Tags: python, pip, artifactory, pypi

I have a proxy pypi repository which can only be updated by a specific user but accessed by all, I have a private pypi repo and a virtual repo to access them.

My problem is that after a while, any pip install on the virtual repo will fail, finding no versions of the module. I tried to reach to it directly via https//myartifactory/proxy_name-cache/.pypi/module_name and I get a 404.

https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-fix-404-error-resource-has-expired/

I learned from here about the expiracy policy, and indeed, if I remove the -cache from the previous URL or if I use my virtual repository instead (without being logged in artifactory), the module is updated and the pip install starts to work.

Why doesn't the pip install command triggers the same mechanism that updates the module and make it downloadable and how can I fix this ?

@EDIT

I'll try to explain better
I've populated the cache from pypi yesterday. Today the artifacts are marked as expired (I can see that by doing a request at https//myartifactory/proxy_name-cache/.pypi/module_name.html which returns a 404)

Therefore, doing a pip install module_name doesn't work (Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ...).

That's my problem

The fact is that if I do the same request that returned me the 404 error, but on proxy_name or virt_name instead of proxy_name-cache, then artifactory updates the artifact with its upstream version and then, it starts to work (until it's marked as expired again)

This behaviour makes me wonder why doing a pip install instead of a simple request (like a curl or with a browser) doesn't update the artifact with its upstream version too

To illustrate my problem :

```
pip install -i https://myartifactory.net/api/pypi/virt/simple requests  # Could not find a version...
curl https://myartifactory.net/pypi-cache/.pypi/requests.html # 404, resource has expired
curl https://myartifactory.net/virt/.pypi/requests.html # 200, returns the html page of versions, meaning it has updated the module with the upstream version
pip install -i https://myartifactory.net/api/pypi/virt/simple requests  # Is now working
```

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. You wrote that the command for the virtual repository doesn't work, and later on wrote " if I remove the -cache from the previous URL or if I use my virtual repository instead (without being logged in artifactory), the module is updated and the pip install starts to work." so I'm not sure what the issue is.. Can you please explain it more clearly?

Comment: I tried to be clearer, I edited the original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the additional information :)

So the issue here is that Artifactory is marking the metadata/index files (on remote repositories) as expirable, that in order to make sure that the metadata/index files are up to date.

In your case, you don't want to give users the ability to change the data, fetch from the remote by them selfs) and for that reason you want them to direct to the '-cache' repository.

To achieve what you want you can move/copy the content from the remote repository to a local repository. This will make sure that Artifactory will calculate the metadata and it won't be expirable as in the remote repository.

In case of copy, if you are worried about duplication of space, don't be as Artifactory has checksum based storage which means that it doesn't matter how many copies of the artifact you have as it will only create an additional pointer in the database meaning a link from the original file to that pointer :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I'll dig into it. I'm just not sure how this copy works. Is it something that can be done automatically ? Are you suggesting something like this : https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-do-i-replicate-remote-repository-cache-in-one-artifactory-to-another-artifactory/ ?

Comment: Not really, the KB you posted is about replication. I meant to use copy, it can be by a script that is running on a cron based on your system and trigger the rest api for copy/move or to write a user plugin (only on pro version) to be triggered on afterCreate closure.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Last things : there is no way to deactivate the expiracy thing ? The modules we use are all release versions that are not supposed to change. Also, the fact that doing an unauthenticated pip install on the virtual repo triggers doesn't trigger the update of the module but doing a simple unauthenticated curl on an index file on the same virtual repo does update the module, is it a bug or the expected behaviour ? Because it bothers me a bit not to be able to use directly the remote pypi proxy repository and having to find a workaround.

Comment: You can change the expiry on the repository configuration --> Advanced tab. You have the caching param.  PLEASE NOTE that this is not recommended as you won't be able to fetch new artifacts if they were published after your last resolution AND the time of the cache expiry had not elapsed.